# Adding UIImagePickerController onto an already open UIPopoverController

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have a popover which contains a tableview, once a row has been selected I want to then push on a UIImagePickerController.

According to the documents on the Apple website, I can only present this in a new view controller. How do I present a popover, in a popover? Or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a delegate and dismiss the tableview on didSelectRowAtIndex using either an exit unWind segue or by dismissing the popover manually using a delegate. Then present the popOver containing the UIImagePickerController. You could also just use the delegate to display a popover along with the tableview although that probably would look cluttered.